# Android How to add clickable button in listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i am displaying Listview with some movie and right side display button for download but when i scroll Listview then button event interchange(Repaint) every time,i have set button text cancel when user press download button and downloading get started but when scroll down list then button text change initial name with download and event get interchange.

```
 static class listitemcontainers
{
     //ImageView imgIcon;
     //TextView txtTitle;
     ProgressBar pb;
     TextView progressval;
     Button downloadbutton;
     TextView title;
     ImageView imageicon;
     LinearLayout layout; 
}

       @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview,final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final listitemcontainers holder;
    Log.d("Game Name in adapter",":"+GameListname.get(position));

     View vi=convertview;

     final listitemcontainers holdz;
    RelativeLayout RL;

    if(convertview==null)
    {

        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);    

         holder = new listitemcontainers();

          holder.title = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.game_name);
          holder.imageicon=(ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.listicon);

             RL=(RelativeLayout)convertview.findViewById(R.id.game_row);
             holder.layout = (LinearLayout )convertview.findViewById(R.id.dynamic);

               holder.progressval=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.progressval);
               holder.pb=(ProgressBar)convertview.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
               holder.pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

               holder.downloadbutton=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.button1);

         convertview.setTag(holder);

    final listitemcontainers hold = holder;

       //setButtonClick(hold );


    }
    else {
         holder = (listitemcontainers)convertview.getTag();

      }


          holder.title.setText(GameListname.get(position));

          holder.imageicon.setImageDrawable(GameIcon.get(position));

          holder.downloadbutton.setText("Dwnload"+position);

          holder.downloadbutton.setId(position);

          holder.pb.setId(position+1000);


          setButton(holder,convertview,position);


       return convertview;
}
 int globalid;

   public void setButton(final listitemcontainers holder,final View v,final int id){
            holder.downloadbutton=(Button)v.findViewById(id);
            holder.pb=(ProgressBar)v.findViewById(id+1000);
          holder.downloadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Click By:"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(checkflag==true){
                checkflag=false;
                globalid=id;
             UpdateProgresBar.listcntr=holder;


          up=new UpdateProgresBar(holder.pb,activity,v);
          up.execute("");

          CancleButtonClick(holder,v,id);
            }

         else{
             Toast.makeText(activity, "Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }




        }
    });

}
```

Comment: how you change names ? post code.

Comment: You should check out my new library that makes writing adapters much easier.. including of course what you need - adding clickable buttons inside your items. http://amigold.github.io/FunDapter/

Answer (score 0):

you should use view holder inside Listview or you will have to check convertview null properly before inflating UI.